# How to pick up a changed item using a TJvInspector where the item is a TStrings?

Tags: delphi

I want to know when I have changed a component using a TJvInspector. The OnDataValueChanged event fires fine for this most of the time but I have a property that has a TStrings value and the TJVInspector has a registered item editor for TStrings ( TJvInspectorTStringsItem ) but I can't see how to get any notification when this event has changed. The OnDataValueChanged event never fires, nor does any other useful event. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug with the component but I don't want to edit the JVCS code.  So what I have done is create my own editor and an OnChange event that I can pick up.

```
procedure TFormMain.RegisterMyJvInspectorTypes;
begin
  TJvCustomInspectorData.ItemRegister.Add( TJvInspectorTypeInfoRegItem.Create( TMyInspectorTStringsItem, TypeInfo( TStrings ) ) );
end;

procedure TFormMain.barFileImportBeforeEdit( Sender: TObject; Item: TJvCustomInspectorItem; Edit: TCustomEdit );
begin
  if ( Item is TMyInspectorTStringsItem ) then
    TMyInspectorTStringsItem( Item ).OnChange := OnStringsValueChanged;
end;
```